# Gmail test acct

Tags: email

I need to test an email sign up script, where the user inputs their email and password and the script retrieves their address book and then sends out a welcome email to join site. Thoughts on how I can test for large contact list email? How can I impport a ton of emails into a test gmail acct?

Comment: Can you clarify: Thoughts on how I can test for large contact list email?

Answer (score 2):

> How can I import a ton of emails into a test gmail acct?

[The Google Email Uploader](http://mail.google.com/mail/help/email_uploader.html)

([Instructions](http://www.cjvandyk.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=157))